# How to change color of UIActionSheet in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, customization, xcode5

I wish I could use custom colors to display Actionsheet in iOS 7.I've been searching for proper answer since couple of days.
Any help will be appreciated Thanks..

I'm using UIActionsheet to display PickerView in it

Answer (score 3):

```
 UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy.
 If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the
 UIActionSheet API, you can create your own.
```

As per apple doc [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

So you have to use some custom class for that,

show this [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/uiactionsheet).

Answer (score 3):

I want to stress that this violates Apple's rules, but this works:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    [actionSheet.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
          UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
          button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
          NSString *buttonText = button.titleLabel.text;
          if ([buttonText isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)]) {
             [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          }
      }
  }];
}
```

(conform to `UIActionSheetDelegate`)

Comment: Any idea why the colors shows correctly in Portrait mode but if i launch the UIActionView in landscape i can see only cancel button colored but others are just in black.

Comment: Perhaps UIActionSheet wraps the top buttons in another view? So you'll need to recursively run through. You honestly don't want to be trying to do this kind of thing though. It will likely break in future versions of iOS since you're not meant to. Getting through the review process might be tricky too.

Answer (score 1):

I have created class which extedns UIActionSheet funcionality with ability to set colors, fonts, text colors and images to Action Sheet buttons. It works fine both for iOs6 and iOs7, and both for iPhone and iPad applications.
https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet
It doesn't use hidden API, so it's safety for Appstore. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Man, Will going to download and test it